# exceptional Hermitian symmetric spaces - models and Riemannian metrics

Tags: complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

There are two compact exceptional Hermitian symmetric spaces. The complexified octonionic projective plane $\mathrm{E_6/U(1)Spin(10)}$:

Q1: What exactly is the complexified octonionic projective plane?

Q2: Can we describe explicitly the Riemannian metric using octonions? This can be answered in two possible ways:

1. The isotropy representation can be written down using complexified octonions so how does the $\mathrm{Spin(10)}$-invariant inner product look like?
2. This space can be identified as a minimal closed orbit in the complex projectivization of the complex exceptional Jordan algebra $\mathcal{J}_3(\mathbb{O_C})$. (This minimal orbit should be given by $[A] \in \mathbb{CP}^{26}$ for $A \in \mathcal{J}_3(\mathbb{O_C})$ of "octonionic rank 1.") Is the Riemannian metric in question pullback of some $\mathrm{E_6}$-invariant object that lives on this complex Jordan algebra? I'd prefer this way as it would extend the case of real octonionic planes that I've considered in my [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217761/riemannian-metric-of-hyperbolic-plane).

and the other one $\mathrm{E_7/U(1)E_6}$:

Q3: Is there a nice model of this space as in the case Q2.2?

Q4: The isotropy representation is the complexified Jordan algebra. What is the $\mathrm{E_6}$-invariant scalar product?

Comment: As far as 2, goes, I assume you mean the *projectivization* of a minimal closed orbit in the complex exceptional Jordan algebra.  In that case, yes, as Élie Cartan explained in his 1894 thesis, if you take the $\mathrm{E}_6$-invariant cubic form $J$ on this algebra and look at the cone cut out by the Jacobian ideal of $J$ (a linear system of quadrics), this is a 17-dimensional cone that projectivizes to the (minimal) 16-dimensional $\mathrm{E}^\mathbb{C}_6$-orbit in $\mathbb{CP}^{26}$.  It is homogeneous under any maximal compact subgroup of $\mathrm{E}^\mathbb{C}_6$.

Comment: For the $\mathrm{E}_7$ symmetric space, look at its minimal irreducible representation, which has (complex) dimension $56$.  In this representation, the group preserves a quartic form Q (and a symplectic form, but you don't need that).  If you let $I$ be the ideal generated by the quadrics that are second partials of $Q$, it cuts out a cone of dimension $28$.  When you projectivize it, you get the 27-dimensional homogeneous space of $\mathrm{E}^\mathbb{C}_7$ embedded into $\mathbb{CP}^{55}$.  It is homogeneous under any maximal compact in  $\mathrm{E}^\mathbb{C}_7$.  (Also in Cartan's thesis.)

Comment: @RobertBryant Yes, I forgot about projectivization. Thank you. Now that you've written down the $\mathrm{E_7}$ case I remember seeing this representation under the name Freudenthal vector space.